# What does, "supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target" mean?

Tags: typescript

I'm working on an Angular (1.4.9) application with TypeScript. I'm doing an $http post and am using a method to trigger an alert for success or failure on a registration page. I realized that I would have to pass in the context of the method I'm using to trigger the alert and so, typically, I would do something like:

```
public showAlert(alertType: string, alertTitle: string, alertMessage: string, alertTimeout: number): void {
    this.alertShow = true;
    this.alertType = alertType;
    this.alertTitle = alertTitle;
    this.alertMessage = alertMessage;
    this.alertTimeout = alertTimeout;
}

public postIt(): void {
    that: any = this; // <-- See, I know what I'm doing.

    var url: string = "/";
    var user: any = {};

    this.$http.post(url, user)
        .then((data: any) => {
            that.showAlert("success", "Yes!", "You are registered.");
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
            that.showAlert("warning", "Embarrassing...", "Problem on our end. Try again, later.");
        });
}
```

But, then I'm like, "Isn't TypeScript smart enough to know what I'm doing, here? Aren't the arrow functions taking care of this for me?" So, I switch it around:

```
public postIt(): void {
    // var that: any = this; <-- Boom! ...Commented out!

    var url: string = "/";
    var user: any = {};

    this.$http.post(url, user)
        .then((data: any) => {
            // it doesn't like the "this"
            this.showAlert("success", "Yes!", "You are registered.");
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
            // it doesn't like the "this"
            this.showAlert("warning", "Embarrassing...", "Problem on our end. Try again, later.");
        });
}
```

I think I'm pretty smart. TypeScript cooperates. I checked the interpreted JavaScript and it's doing just what I thought it would:

```
myClass.prototype.postIt = function () {
    // var that: any = this;
    var _this = this;
    var url = "/";
    var user = {};
    this.$http.post(url, user)
        .then(function (data) {
        _this.showAlert("success", "Yes!", "You are registered.");
    })
        .catch(function (err) {
        _this.showAlert("warning", "Embarrassing...", "Problem on our end. Try again, later.");
    });
```

...And my application works just fine. But, the compiler throws me an error: "TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target." Considering the situation, I want to read that like it can't find the method. When I have it the original way it doesn't make this complaint. Could you explain what this error is about, exactly? Why isn't this error preventing compilation?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Error message actually explains very well what is wrong. Method `showAlert` expects 4 parameters and all of them are required, but inside `postIt` method `showAlert` is called without `alertTimeout` argument. To make this compiler error go away you should either pass `alertTimeout` value when calling `showAlert` or update method's signature and make last parameter optional:

```
public showAlert(alertType: string, alertTitle: string, 
    alertMessage: string, alertTimeout?: number): void {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah-ha! I should have known... That resolves the error, but I've read the compiler wouldn't work if I had that kind of problem (Obviously, it will.) and, then, why didn't the compiler catch the error when I was using `that = this` (Obviously, it won't.)?

Answer (score 3):

If you have added a semi colon at the end of any sections, you will see the same error. I was facing the same issue as I added a semi colon at the end of one module in my `imports` section in `app.module.ts`.

[image]

Just removing a semi colon from `RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);` fixed it for me.

Note: Though it is not related to OP's question, sharing for the other users who land in this page with the same error.